# Verify list elements by Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium

```
WebElement select = myD.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='custfoodtable']/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/select"));
List<WebElement> allOptions = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
for (WebElement option : allOptions) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Value is: %s", option.getAttribute("value")));
    option.click();
    Object vaLue = "Gram";
    if (option.getAttribute("value").equals(vaLue)) {
        System.out.println("Pass");
    } else {
        System.out.println("fail");
    }
}
```

I can verify one element in a list, but there are like 20 elements in a dropdown I need to verify and I do not want to use above logic 20 times. Is there any easier way to do it?

Comment: What are the print results ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the for-each construct. It's only useful when iterating over a single `Iterable` / array. You need to iterate over the `List<WebElement>` and the array simultaneously.

```
// assert that the number of found <option> elements matches the expectations
assertEquals(exp.length, allOptions.size());
// assert that the value of every <option> element equals the expected value
for (int i = 0; i < exp.length; i++) {
    assertEquals(exp[i], allOptions.get(i).getAttribute("value"));
}
```

---

EDIT after OP's changed his question a bit:

Assuming you have an array of expected values, you can do this:

```
String[] expected = {"GRAM", "OUNCE", "POUND", "MILLIMETER", "TSP", "TBSP", "FLUID_OUNCE"};
List<WebElement> allOptions = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

// make sure you found the right number of elements
if (expected.length != allOptions.size()) {
    System.out.println("fail, wrong number of elements found");
}
// make sure that the value of every <option> element equals the expected value
for (int i = 0; i < expected.length; i++) {
    String optionValue = allOptions.get(i).getAttribute("value");
    if (optionValue.equals(expected[i])) {
        System.out.println("passed on: " + optionValue);
    } else {
        System.out.println("failed on: " + optionValue);
    }
}
```

This code essentially does what my first code did. The only real difference is that now you're doing the work manually and are printing the results out.

Before, I used the [`assertEquals()`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) static method from the `Assert` class of the JUnit framework. This framework is a de-facto standard in writing Java tests and the `assertEquals()` method family is the standard way to verify the results of your program. They make sure the arguments passed into the method are equal and if they are not, they throw an `AssertionError`.

Anyway, you can do it the manual way, too, no problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys..But i dnt know if i understand cauz i am very new to this. Actually i tried this too

Comment: This code should go instead of your for-each loop there. You can include your printing, too, if you need to. That said, this should work exactly as needed, it should assert your `<option>` elements' values. Is something wrong when you copypaste it into your test? Does it work as intended? I added comments for you to understand the code more easily.

Comment: Hey I just change my question lil bit. sorry for the confusion earlier. I just want to see if there is any easier way to verify all the elements in list.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..I copy your code but exp is giving me error, I tried to create a local variable but then length show me error length cannot be resolved or is not a field. I had the same problem in your previous answer too.i know i am missing something here. Thanks for ur help

Comment: I am curious about your 1st answer..i am trying to make it work that way too but it gives me error. when i try to see what the error it is create method 'assertsEquals()'

Comment: @user2502733 I assumed (and it was a bad assumption as I see it now) that you know what `assertEquals()` is. One of the usual usages of it is to add a `import static org.junit.Assert.*;` static import to be able to use the method directly. Or qualify it by using `Assert.assertEquals()` instead (no need for the static import then, just the normal one: `import org.junit.Assert`). Make sure your classpath includes [JUnit](http://junit.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
String[] act = new String[allOptions.length];
int i = 0;
for (WebElement option : allOptions) {
    act[i++] = option.getValue();
}

List<String> expected = Arrays.asList(exp);
List<String> actual = Arrays.asList(act);

Assert.assertNotNull(expected);
Assert.assertNotNull(actual);
Assert.assertTrue(expected.containsAll(actual));
Assert.assertTrue(expected.size() == actual.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void verifyElementsInListEquals(List<WebElement> elementsList, String expectedValue) {

    ArrayList<String> TextList =new ArrayList<>(); // new list to have Text from list of Webelement

    for( WebElement x :elementsList){  //for each loop in JAVA
        TextList.add(x.getText());  //add "x" times text to list above
    }

    if(TextList.contains(expectedValue)){  //check if value exist in list above
        System.out.println("Value is there");  
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(" no value");
    assertTrue(false); //will always stop the program here 
    }
}
```