# test display of context menu with selenium webdriver

Tags: html, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a problem to test the display of contxxt menu when i right-click in a compnent

this is my code HTML

```
<div contextmenu="menuContext" class="demo" id="global" style="display:block;"> 
    I do something ...          
</div>
<menu type="context" id="menuContext">                       
    <menuitem id="abc" label="label1" onclick="window.location='page1.html';"></menuitem>
    <menuitem id="def" label="label2" onclick="window.location='page1.html';"></menuitem>
    <menuitem id="ghi" label="label3" onclick="window.location='page3.html';"></menuitem>
    <menuitem id="jkl" label="label4" onclick="window.location='page1.html';"></menuitem>
    <menuitem id="mno" label="label5" onclick="window.location='page2.html';"></menuitem>
</menu>
```

This my selenium test code:

```
private void verifyComponent(final String myId) {
    final WebElement component = this.driver.findElement(By.id(myId));
    final boolean testComponent = component.isDisplayed();
    assertTrue("verification of compnent: ", testComponent);
}

private void verifyMCappearance() {
    final List<WebElement> elementNumList =
            this.driver.findElements(By.id("global"));
    // Taking 1st cell
    final WebElement link = elementNumList.get(0);
    // Right Clicking
    new Actions(this.driver).contextClick(link).perform();
    verifyComponent("menuContext");
}
//call method
verifyMCappearence();
```

so the display of my web page is correct and the right-click works and i see the context menu. but i dont know why i cant test it with assert method !!!
when i see my code html in firebug, even when i right-click or not i have always the code html of context menu hidden  probably that is the problem.

please help!

Comment: the id you're tryihng to pass `verifyComponent("menuContext");` is different from the one in html code `menuContextuel`. Are you aware of it?

Comment: And what do you mean by `i cant test it with assert method ` ? are you getting any errors?

Comment: for your first remark i have only made an error when copy/past.

Comment: for your second remark, yes i'm getting an error that i dont understand! i things the webdriver cant find the id "menucontext"

Comment: please post the error you'r getting

Comment: I made an error when i copy/past my cod. i edit my code

Comment: `Time elapsed : 13.406 sec <<< FAILURE?
        java.lang.AssertionError: verification of compnent:
             at org.junit.assert.fail<Assert.java:88>
             at ....`

Comment: Once you click on the context menu, it will get disappeared. Then the assert will fail, since it is not displayed. But i'm not so sure about the isDisplay method func for contextmenu

Comment: I dont know how to resolve this problem !

Comment: Hope following will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746565/verify-list-elements-by-selenium-webdriver


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428026/select-an-option-from-the-right-click-menu-in-selenium-webdriver-java