# How to check the order of breadcrumbs in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have a header defined as First / Second / Third as a breadcrumbs. I would like to check if the elements are displayed in correct order using selenium with optimal way of coding.

```
<ol class = "breadcrumb"
     <li class="break-all">        
          <a href="..." class="break-all">First</a>
          <span class="divider">/</span> 
   </li>
   <li class="break-all">        
          <a href="..." class="break-all">Second</a>
          <span class="divider">/</span> 
   </li>
   <li class="break-all">        
          <a href="..." class="break-all">Third</a>
          <span class="divider">/</span> 
   </li>
</ol>
```

Now when I do

```
findBy("//ol[@class='breadcrumb']")
```

, I get the whole elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
findBy("//ol[@class='breadcrumb']").getText().equals("First / Second / Third");
```

it should work.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to find all breadcrumb elements, for example, via a `cssSelector()`. Then, for every WebElement in the list call `getText()` to get the actual text:

```
List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("First", "Second", "Third");

List<WebElement> breadcrumbs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ol.breadcrumb li a"));
for (int i = 0; i < expected.length; i++) {
    String breadcrumb = breadcrumbs.get(i).getText();
    if (breadcrumb.equals(expected[i])) {
        System.out.println("passed on: " + breadcrumb);
    } else {
        System.out.println("failed on: " + breadcrumb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, you can follow the below process:

**1- Create an "ArrayList" and add all the items that needs to be compared with.

2- Retrieve the link texts and put it in a new ArrayList.

3- Assert that the two ArrayList matches.**

Below code shall work for you:

```
//Adding all the list items to compare in an ArrayList
ArrayList<String> alist = new ArrayList<String>();
alist.add("First");
alist.add("Second");
alist.add("Third");

//Checking the Arraylist's data
System.out.println("The list values are as under: ");
for(String list_item: alist)
    System.out.println(list_item);

//Creating an ArrayList to store the retrieved link texts
ArrayList<String> List_Compare = new ArrayList<String>();

//Retrieving the link texts and putting them into the Arraylist so created
List<WebElement> New_List = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='break-all']"));
for(WebElement list_item: New_List){
    List_Compare.add(list_item.getText());
}

//Checking the new Arraylist's data
System.out.println("The Retrieved list values are as under: ");
for(String list_item: List_Compare)
    System.out.println(list_item);

//Asserting the original Arraylist matches to the Arraylist with retrieved Link Texts 
try{
    Assert.assertEquals(alist, List_Compare);
    System.out.println("Equal lists");
}catch(Throwable e){
    System.err.println("Lists are not equal. "+e.getMessage());
}
```

**NOTE:** Do import the **Assert class** using **`import junit.framework.Assert;`** for the last part of the code to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a list of known values to compare with. And then use `findElements()` to find all the elements to match your target. In that you also need to carefully write the selector so that it grabs the list of expected elements.
`//a[@class='break-all']` can be used to grab the list of elements you want

```
String[] expected = {"First", "Second", "Third"};
List<WebElement> allOptions = select.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='break-all']"));

// make sure you found the right number of elements
if (expected.length != allOptions.size()) {
    System.out.println("fail, wrong number of elements found");
}
// make sure that the value of every <option> element equals the expected value
for (int i = 0; i < expected.length; i++) {
    String optionValue = allOptions.get(i).getText();
    if (optionValue.equals(expected[i])) {
        System.out.println("passed on: " + optionValue);
    } else {
        System.out.println("failed on: " + optionValue);
    }
}
```

Implementation taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746565/verify-list-elements-by-selenium-webdriver)