# How can i select items from the list

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to get items in the list. All I get is an item from the span. How can I get items in the select. If I don't use span in the css selector, then the script generates an error that the element is not visible.

This is the HTML of the page:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <div class="select2-container select2-container-active" id="s2id_agency" style="width: 150px;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   
                <span>01_me</span>
                <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close" style="display:none;"></abbr>   
                <div>
                <b></b>
                </div>
                </a>
                <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text"></div>
                <select name="agency" id="agency" style="width:150px;" class="select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1">
                <option value="14814">01_me</option>
                <option value="14333">A_RLAgency</option>
                <option value="14771">Agency_20150111183734</option>
                <option value="14254">RLAgency</option>
                <option value="14065">unknown_agency</option></select>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</tbody>
```

This is my script:

```
        try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        List<String> displayed = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<WebElement> verifyAgency = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By
                .cssSelector("#s2id_agency > a.select2-choice > span")));


        System.out.println("NUMBER OF ROWS IN THIS TABLE = "
                + verifyAgency.size());


        for (WebElement element : verifyAgency) {
            System.out.println("" + element.getText());
            displayed.add(element.getText());
            sorted.add(element.getText());
        }

        Collections.sort(sorted);
        log.info(sorted);
        if (!displayed.equals(sorted)) {

            final String failedMsg = "Agency is not in alphabatical ordr.";
            log.error(failedMsg, null);
            boolean passed = false;
            Assert.assertFalse(passed, failedMsg);
            System.out.println(failedMsg);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        final String failedMsg = "Failed trying to check agency names in alphabetical order.";
        log.error(failedMsg, null);
        boolean passed = false;
        Assert.assertFalse(passed, failedMsg);
        System.out.println(failedMsg);
    }
```

Comment: What is your requirement? Just print the options?

Comment: yes, make sure that they are in alphabetical order. Thanks Saifur!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out with this code:

```
Select objSelect = new Select(dw2.findElement(By.id("agency")));
List<WebElement> lstOptions = objSelect.getOptions();
boolean sorted = false;
for (int i = 0; i < lstOptions.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (lstOptions.get(i).getText()
        .compareTo(lstOptions.get(i + 1).getText()) > 0) { // Checking sorting based on natural sort
    sorted = false;
    break;
    }
    sorted = true;
}
if (sorted)
    System.out.println("Sorted");
else
    System.out.println("Un-sorted");
```

Comment: Vivek, your code sorts the items, however it outputs,[[[[[FirefoxWebDriver: firefox on MAC (f8d9d3fa-6e73-ce47-8a14-aa2193065313)] -> id: agency]] -> tag name: option]. I am trying to output items from the list as well. Is it possible from the html that I have on the page? Thanks!

Comment: Am not sorting the list anywhere in my code. Am just comparing list elements. You are getting that op cause u r printing webelement object. To print options sysout lstOptions.get(i).getText().

Comment: Thanks Much, Vivek, It worked! Also, Thanks Much to Saifur. It was my bad that i was not outputting the correct way. Keep up the good work, Guys!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to use `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy` on select list options which are not visible. Infact according to your requirement you don't need them to be visible. You can alternatively use `presenceOfElementLocated`
and to grab the list simple `SelectElement` class should be enough

*Note: mine is C#*

```
    IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='agency']"));

    SelectElement selectList = new SelectElement(element);
    IList<IWebElement> options = selectList.Options;
```

And, if that's a static list you can avoid all of this quirky work and simply do

```
    IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='agency']"));    
    SelectElement selectList = new SelectElement(element);

    var isTrue = selectList.getText().equals("01_me / A_RLAgency / Agency_20150111183734 / RLAgency / unknown_agency")
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925787/how-to-check-the-order-of-breadcrumbs-in-selenium/27925944#27925944)

Comment: the list is not static. When i use List<WebElement> options = selectList.getOptions();   I get this output, rather than items in the list    [[[[[FirefoxWebDriver: firefox on MAC (cd757b01-65de-6444-a748-e2f3ba74f7c3)] -> xpath: //*[@id='agency']]] -> tag name: option]]. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: try using `//select[@id='agency']` instead

Comment: can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: I don't think i have this privilege yet to post screenshots, but which screenshot are you referring to though? Thanks!

Comment: Use [imgur](http://imgur.com/) to upload. I want to see the select element and how it is embedded.

Comment: try this `WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("s2id_agency")));

myDynamicElement.click();

WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='agency']//options")));

SelectElement selectList = new SelectElement(myDynamicElement);
IList<IWebElement> options = selectList.Options;  ` I guess you have to click open the list. I guess it is being populated with some kind of javascript

Comment: giving me this message now org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "div"

Comment: Does it open the div?

Comment: it does not open anything...waits for a few seconds, and then fails

Comment: when i use this element (By.cssSelector("#s2id_agency > a.select2-choice > span")));           I get this error   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "span". The element does click on the dropdown list, but i am not sure if that matters for what I am trying to achieve