# Create a Reusable method to Verify list elements by Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium

I am new to this site and don't know how things show up here. I was reading the post from below where String array is being used to ListwebElements.

[Verify list elements by Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746565/verify-list-elements-by-selenium-webdriver/33151208#33151208)

String[] expected = {"GRAM", "OUNCE", "POUND", "MILLIMETER", "TSP", "TBSP", "FLUID_OUNCE"};

I am trying to do something similar using String Array trying to get different buttons on a UI page. I want to make this method reusable by changing the "expected" list per test. Does anyone know how you would make this method Reusable?

In my case, "expected" list is different each time depending on a page.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the custom annotation for reusing purpose. Please see the example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/).

If you are using JUnit you can also use [parameterized test](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hi @JeffC thanks for your comment! My intention was not a links but the ideas how to solve the problem. I am not sure that the good answer requires copy of the implementation example. But sorry this is meta discussion.